# Using Database Change Notification on multiple tables

Tags: c#, .net, database, oracle, notifications

I am developing an application in C# where I'm trying to use Oracle Database Change Notification.

When I'm using DCN for one table, everything is working as expected but when I am trying to use two tables, I get the following error: "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt", on the line cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Here is the code:

```
string sql = "select rowid, first_name, last_name, salary from employees where employee_id = :1" +
                 "select country_id, country_name, region_id from countries where country_id = :2";
string constr = "User Id=hr;Password=Parola_007;Data Source=ORCL;Pooling=false";
con = new OracleConnection(constr);
con.Open();
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, con);

OracleParameter p_id = new OracleParameter();
p_id.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Decimal;
p_id.Value = 149;
OracleParameter p_id2 = new OracleParameter();
p_id2.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
p_id2.Value = "BE";

cmd.BindByName = true;
cmd.Parameters.Add(p_id);
cmd.Parameters.Add(p_id2);

OracleDependency dep = new OracleDependency(cmd);
cmd.Notification.IsNotifiedOnce = false;
dep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDatabaseNotification);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    public static void OnDatabaseNotification(object src, OracleNotificationEventArgs args)
    {
        string sql = "select rowid, first_name, last_name, salary from employees where rowid = :1" +
                         "select rowid, country_id, country_name, region from countries where rowid = :2";

        OracleParameter p_rowid = new OracleParameter();
        p_rowid.Value = args.Details.Rows[0]["rowid"];
        OracleParameter p_rowid2 = new OracleParameter();
        p_rowid2.Value = args.Details.Rows[1]["rowid"];

        OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.BindByName = true;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p_rowid);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p_rowid2);

        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dr.Read();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Database Change Notification received!");
        DataTable changeDetails = args.Details;
        Console.WriteLine("Resource {0} has changed.", changeDetails.Rows[0]["ResourceName"]);
        Console.WriteLine("Resource {1} has changed.", changeDetails.Rows[1]["ResourceName"]);

        dr.Dispose();
        cmd.Dispose();
        p_rowid.Dispose();
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't done DCN in C# but I you generally can't send two separate, independent statements to Oracle using a single handle.  I'd expect that you'd two separate variables for the two statements (i.e. `sql_1` and `sql_2`), separate commands, etc.

Answer (score 0):

1: you cannot do 2 sql in 1 command.
2: You can use the table trigger in oracle to check the changed table data. All changes should be logged in a table and only need to be query from that table.
sorry for my english